# Como saber se estou em uma pagina anônima ou normal chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Estou a fazer uma página `html` para **usar localmente no meu PC** com *Windows*, mas precisava de alguma forma de saber em que modo estou no browser `Chrome`. Pretendia apresentar uma frase que iria mudar consoante o modo em que estive-se.

**Exemplo:**

- Incognito Mode

  Esta página está em modo anônimo!
- Normal Mode

  Esta página está em modo normal!

Já tentei este exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w49x9f1a/) mas sem sucesso.

**Edit1:**

---

Consegui obter resultado pretendido com o exemplo do jsfilddle tal como mencionou o @TomMelo. Mas no meu caso fiz upload para um servidor, no entanto o que preciso é de usar localmente sem a necessidade de usar um server, existe alguma outra forma para o fazer?

Answer (score 20):

Não recomendo fazer esse tipo de verificação.

Uma requisição HTTP precisa conter, de forma bem resumida, apenas o endereço a se obter, a forma de obtenção (i.e.: GET) e opcionalmente parâmetros para a página. Quaisquer dados além disso são cortesia do navegador. Tanto que é trivial fazer um cliente que se passa por um navegador qualquer.

A intenção do modo anônimo é justamente passar o mínimo de dados possíveis à página que se deseja obter. Se você decidir obter os dados que o navegador pretende ocultar, você já entrou em um jogo de gato e rato. É exatamente por esse motivo que algumas soluções proposta em duas respostas anteriores (já apagadas e somente visíveis para quem tem mais de 10 mil pontos) já funcionaram um dia, mas não funcionam mais hoje.

Se você conseguir algo que funcione hoje, amanhã poderá não funcionar mais. E quando parar de funcionar, vai ser sem aviso, e você vai ter que correr atrás de outra gambiarra.

Finalmente, a solução desta tarde é utilizar a API do sistema de arquivos, que de vez em quando tem um comportamento diferente em modo incognito. Quando essa técnica começar a ser bastante utilizada (não demora muito), o pessoal do Chromium vai dar um jeito de resolver isso. Até lá, você pode arriscar sua sorte. Você pode encontrar a documentação sobre como usá-la na MDN, mas mesmo lá você já começa seu estudo com este aviso (ênfases minhas):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. **Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user.** There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and **the behavior may change in the future**.

Em português:

> Esta funcionalidade não é padrão e não está na trilha dos padrões a serem implementados. **Não utilize isso em sites em produção e acessíveis pela Web: isso não funcionará para todos os usuários.** Podem haver grandes incompatibilidades entre implementações e **o comportamento pode mudar no futuro**.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, o uso que ia dar era caseiro e para uma coisa bem simples, tal como referi era somente para mostrar a mensagem, vou tentar aprofundar mais e tentar descobrir alguma coisa e aguardar que alguém me consiga ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

A [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) é desabilitada no modo Incognito. O código que você mencionou funciona...

```
var fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
fs(window.TEMPORARY, 10, function() {
   console.log('modo normal');
}, function(error) {
   console.log('modo incognito');
});
```

**Detalhe**: Caso você tente abrir o arquivo (.html) no browser:

`file:///diretorio/arquivo.html`

esse código sempre exibirá a [mensagem do callback de erro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction#file).

Teste sua página através do Apache, por exemplo.

**EDIT**

---

Como já foi mencionado nas respostas anteriores, essa validação não é recomendada(não implementar para rodar em produção).

Porém, se é apenas um teste para rodar na máquina local, você pode tentar a validação através da api FileSystem.

Comment: A MDN já começa a página do link com um aviso: *This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. **Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user.** There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.*

Comment: Sim, isso não é pra ser usado em produção. É apenas pro caso do autor que está "fazendo página html para usar localmente no PC com Windows"

Comment: @TomMelo existe alguma forma de o poder fazer mas sem a necessidade de um server?

Comment: @Tmc acredito que se você abrir o Chrome com a flag --allow-file-access-from-files deva funcionar...Lembrando que isso é apenas pra testes. Você precisa fazer isso mesmo?

Comment: O problema que dessa solução numa próxima atualização eles podem simplesmente corta o script e você ter que correr atrás de outra PoG para resolver isso.

Answer (score 0):

Tente este simples código:

```
var fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
if (!fs) {
  console.log("check failed?");
} else {
  fs(window.TEMPORARY,
     100,
     console.log.bind(console, "not in incognito mode"),
     console.log.bind(console, "incognito mode"));
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17741714/7934535

Comment: tem alguma solução para chrome?

Comment: @Tmc eu procurei, mas nenhuma solução que achei realmente funciona